# Using method from base class as final

Tags: c++, inheritance, final

I have a service class which later will be used for storing multiple implementations in one container to call `Process` on all of them

```cpp
struct Service
{
    virtual ~Service();
    virtual void Process() = 0;
};
```

There are two services which share common logic, so instead of copying code i've created common base class which i forbid to create manually by making constructor protected

```cpp
struct CommonServiceLogic : Service
{
protected:
    CommonServiceLogic();
    void Process() final override {
        /*do smth common*/
        ProcessImpl();
    }
    virtual void ProcessImpl();
};
```

Now i can define my services next way

```cpp
struct EasyService : CommonServiceLogic {
    using CommonServiceLogic::ProcessImpl;
};

struct ComplicatedService : CommonServiceLogic {
    void ProcessImpl() final override {
        /*do smth special*/
        CommonServiceLogic::ProcessImpl();
    }
};
```

Questions:

1. Can i somehow mark `EasyService::ProcessImpl` as final? I can do it by redefining a method, but is there some language way?

Reason for marking this method as final is pretty simple: i want to show (to compiler or to next programmer) that this override is the last one. `using` allows to create a child from `EasyService` with redefinition of `ProcessImpl`.

Note that i cannot finalize `ComplicatedService` and `EasyService` for reasons which is hard to explain

2. Is there even reason to do it from a compiler point of view? `Service::Process` will be called in the place which does not know about `EasyService` nor `ComplicatedService`

Comment: What trouble are you having with your current code? Note that `final override` is redundant; `final` implies `override`. Read more at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final

Comment: @AndyG i've edited the question explicitly specifying what my problem with code is. See reason for question 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, then you are asking whether you can apply `final` to a function from the superclass that was imported using `using`. This does not seem to be possible unless you redefine the virtual function in `EasyService`, so your fix seems like the correct option.